Aggregating linestring geometry data to a grid
I am trying to aggregate data for road segments to a fixed grid using geopandas.
The road data looks like this:
|Variable | geometry |
|---------|----------|
| 59  |LINESTRING (440735.351 4319767.843, 440733.320...|
| 48  |LINESTRING (440733.320 4319607.463, 440732.508...|
| 64  |LINESTRING (440858.641 4329887.089, 440853.551...|
| 64  |LINESTRING (440920.578 4330030.844, 440890.661...|
| 68  |LINESTRING (218573.705 4257347.137, 218586.697...|   

The fixed grid I want to aggregate the road data appears as:
|geometry|
|--------|
| POLYGON ((238749.978 4498509.611, 238898.825 4..|
| POLYGON ((240086.217 4498360.636, 240234.824 4... |
| POLYGON ((241421.845 4498211.925, 241570.857 4..|
| POLYGON ((242758.152 4498063.434, 242906.923 4... |
| POLYGON ((244094.479 4497914.762, 244243.009 4... |

I am currently trying to weight the variable by the road length, apply a spatial join, multiplying the weighted by the road length within the grid cell and summing over the grid for all roads using this code:
gdf_road['weighted_variable'] = gdf_road['Variable']/ gdf_road.geometry.legnth
gdf_joined = gpd.sjoin(gdf_road, gdf_grid, how="inner", op='intersects')
gdf_grid['agg_variable']=(gdf_joined['Weighted_Variable'] * gdf_joined.geometry.length).groupby(gdf_joined['index_right']).sum()

The result of this code is data that maintains the spatial structure of the original road data, but the magnitude of the variable seems erroneously high. I am curious if there is something I may have overlooked in my logic of aggregating road data to a grid -- perhaps in double counting overlapping roads, not applying another type of weighting scheme...etc. Any suggestions would be great. Thank you!

Are all your linestrings already segmented by the grid or where's the part that's responsible for "road length within the grid cell"  ?

@margusl - I have narrowed down the problem from the code above. When I conduct the spatial join -- it is joining the road segment with the grid cell, but not specifically isolating the length of the road segment directly within that grid cell (meaning, the road segment is paired with the grid cell, but the road may actually extend well outside the grid cell). Therefore, I need to modify the code to only consider where the road is within the grid cell... which is surprisingly harder to do than I originally expected.

gdf_grid.overlay(gdf_road, how='intersection')? This should pretty much solve your problem as you can then sum up the lengths of all resulting road sections within each grid cell.

Hey - this looks like it gets the job done! Thank you!

gdf.overlay seemed to do the trick
gdf_road['weighted_variable'] = gdf_road['Variable']/ gdf_road.geometry.legnth
gdf_join = gpd.overlay(gdf_road, gdf_grid, how="intersection")
gdf_join['new_length'] =  gdf_join.to_crs('EPSG:26916').geometry.length
gdf_join['new_variable'] = gdf_join['weighted_variable'] * gdf_join['new_length']

# Spatial join & aggregate data 
joined_data = gpd.sjoin(gdf_join, gdf_grid, how="inner", op="within")
grouped_data = joined_data.groupby('index_right')
agg_data = grouped_data[['new_variable']].sum().reset_index()

